# AzureDevOps CosmosDB enableTTL without default using runbook or template

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ttl, azure-runbook

I need to edit an existing powershell runbook which uses a template to create a cosmosDb in Azure.

I need to enable TTL without a default TTL value, in the examples I found so far there is always a value, this means that this value is used to delete expired documents.

How do I enable only the TTL without setting a default?

My reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-with-powershell#create-container-unique-key-ttl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live) I found this key table with examples:

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TTL on item |                               Result                               |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TTL on container is set to null (DefaultTimeToLive = null)                       |
|                                                                                  |
| ttl = null  | TTL is disabled. The item will never expire (default).             |
| ttl = -1    | TTL is disabled. The item will never expire.                       |
| ttl = 2000  | TTL is disabled. The item will never expire.                       |
|             |                                                                    |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TTL on container is set to -1 (DefaultTimeToLive = -1)                           |                                                                                  |
|                                                                                  |
| ttl = null  | TTL is enabled. The item will never expire (default).              |
| ttl = -1    | TTL is enabled. The item will never expire.                        |
| ttl = 2000  | TTL is enabled. The item will expire after 2000 seconds.           |
|             |                                                                    |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TTL on container is set to 1000 (DefaultTimeToLive = 1000)                                          |
|                                                                                  |
| ttl = null  | TTL is enabled. The item will expire after 1000 seconds (default). |
| ttl = -1    | TTL is enabled. The item will never expire.                        |
| ttl = 2000  | TTL is enabled. The item will expire after 2000 seconds.           |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is not exactly referred to runbook and template but if I set -1 I can achieve my intent, as shown in the table above, setting in the container a TTL -1, this will be enabled and the TTL value in the documents will be used.

Using `Get-Help New-CosmosDbCollection -full` I could find the parameter `-DefaultTimeToLive`, this is what I am going to use because it looks like there is no option to do it in the [ARM Template](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/36978874-allow-configuring-default-ttl-on-a-cosmosdb-at-col)